# Javascript - Combine and restructure object with special property

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am currently working on a node.js backend code with mysql database.

**Scenario**: I got a branch object (`branchObj`) and branch quantity ary-of-obj (`dbResult`) returned from database. I need to modify and combine them into a new object as shown below but I'm kind of stuck for a while.

**branch list**

```
var branchObj = {
    '1': 'US Branch',
    '2': 'India Branch',
    '5': 'Russia Branch'
}
```

**branch quantity ary-of-obj**

```
var stockResult = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.query(sql, [[productIDAry]],
      (err, dbResult) => {
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(dbResult, null, 5));

        console.log(dbResult);
        // dbResult = [
        //   RowDataPacket {
        //       id: 35,
        //       product_id: 51,
        //       '1_quantity': 3.9,
        //       '2_quantity': 3.2,
        //       '5_quantity': null
        //   },
        //   RowDataPacket {
        //       id: 36,
        //       product_id: 52,
        //       '1_quantity': 3.1,
        //       '2_quantity': 3.1,
        //       '5_quantity': null
        //   }
        // ]

        // below is my code for trying to combine branchObj and dbResult by mapping("1" => "1_quantity") 
        // and restructure
        const result = dbResult.reduce((map, obj) => {
          console.log(branchObj);
          console.log(obj.product_id); // this is fine
          console.log(obj.1_quantity); 
          // an error occur, I noticed the 1_quantity is not a property
          // it has a fixed pattern return from db : (int)_quantity

          return map;
        }, {});

        resolve(result);
      });
  });
```

**What I'd like to achieve**

```
stockResult = {
    '51': {
      'US Branch': 3.1,
      'India Branch': 3.1,
      'Russia Branch': 0
    },
    '52': {
      'US Branch': 3.9,
      'India Branch': 3.2,
      'Russia Branch': 0
    }
  }

Note: "51" is obj.product_id
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In the object dot property syntax, the property must be a valid JavaScript identifier.  1_quantity is not a valid identifier.  So you have to use bracket notation `obj["1_quantity"]`  Or a different property name.

Comment: @James Noted with thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take two nested reduce and build in the inner the objects for a branch and the puter for collecting al branches.

```js
const
    branchObj = { 1: 'US Branch', 2: 'India Branch', 5: 'Russia Branch' },
    dbResult = [{ id: 35, product_id: 51, '1_quantity': 3.9, '2_quantity': 3.2, '5_quantity': null }, { id: 36, product_id: 52, '1_quantity': 3.1, '2_quantity': 3.1, '5_quantity': null }],
    stockResult = dbResult.reduce((r, { id, product_id, ...o }) => {
        r[product_id] = Object.entries(o).reduce((q, [k, v]) => {
            q[branchObj[k.split('_', 1)[0]]] = v || 0;            
            return q;
        }, {});
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(stockResult);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I really appreciate!